# REGEX - '$' needed for match but it also means every new line gets matched, is there another solution?

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a regex which looks like this:

```
((C1)(.*?))?((C2)(.*?))?((C3)(.*?))?((C4)(.*?))?(\.zip|$)
```

"C" stands for Constant here, they are always the same. What comes in-between them is different every time (and sometimes nothing/whitespace. Please see my working example here!

https://regex101.com/r/R1Btde/2

This matches anything from

```
C1 Anything C2 Anything C3 Anything C4 Anything.zip
or
C3 Anything C4 Anything.zip
```

to something without an extension like:

```
C1 Anything C4 Anything
```

The problem is at the moment I am having to end my REGEX with `(\.zip|$)` to make the `.zip` file extension optional (as some files will be directories). Unfortunatelty this matches 'Nothing' every time.

Is there a way of stopping Group 13 matching with the end of every line, whilst still maintaining this group structure? You can see the groups on my working example. This isn't a duplication of my previous question, it's just a continuation as I try to improve this REGEX to support directories and files without extensions. I really appreciate the help you guys have given me and I wouldn't have got this far without you!

Many thanks!

Comment: @Wiktor I don't think that duplicate is correct here. He is asking about making a subexpression optional. The fact that every group is optional and that as a consequence the pattern *does* match empty strings was not his original question...

Comment: @UnbearableLightness The regex in the question can match an empty string. OP asks how to make it stop matching empty strings. The post I linked to is a perfect dupe reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have the MULTILINE flag (ie “m”) turned on, which makes `$` match newlines too.

To make `.zip` optional at the end, end your regex with:

```
(\.zip)?
```

instead of `(\.zip|$)`.

In order to not match the empty string, add a look ahead for something:

```
^(?!$)...your regex here...(\.zip)?
```

Comment: That's not enough, since all his patterns are optional that [will match an empty string too](https://regex101.com/r/R1Btde/5).

Comment: @UnbearableLightness updated answer.